# Unknown issues installing jdk

Tags: java, installation, jdk

I'm trying to install the latest jdk (7u2) onto my Windows XP laptop and for some reason when I double-click the jdk-7u12-windows-i586.exe, no automatic pop up comes out like how I expect it to for the installation. Would anyone know any reasons why it would do that or how to debug this? I have uninstalled any older Java versions, so it should be a clean slate, but nothing is still coming up when I double-click the installer. I have also tried to run the installer on the cmd but nothing comes up as well.  I don't get any warnings or errors. Thank you.

Edit: The installer is not corrupted.  I have tested the installer on another WinXP machine and it works fine.  I am thinking my setup is somehow messed up or one of my other programs are blocking it.. I have disabled a virus scan .exe process in my Windows Task Manager already but it must be something else...

Comment: There should be a log in `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Temp`.  If not, run the installer from the command line with the option `jdk-7u12-windows-i586.exe /LV* C:\jdk.log` (Or your desired path and filename.)  Let's see what the log says.

Comment: Download the installer again. It was corrupted during file transfer.

Comment: @Aaron Copley - I tried your command, but it seems like no jdk.log is saving in the C:\ directory.  (??)

Comment: @mailq - I redownloaded the installer but I am still having the same symptoms.  I am assuming that downloading the jdk does not require a jre since I believe the jdk emcompasses the jre as well...

Comment: Are you running as Admin?

Comment: Also, is this the *full* installer or an online installer?  Try the offline installer.  http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: I do have admin rights.  It should be the full installer that I got from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html  The offline installer looks to only be for the jre and not the jdk.

Comment: Of course... JDK not JRE. Sorry.. (And JDK is full install only.)  Have any luck with this in the last few days?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I haven't touched this problem in awhile.. I think the problem was fixed with something small tucked away in the corner.  Try checking to see if your firewall is turned ON.  Was that it?

Answer (score 1):

This bug is believed to be due to the way that the JDK7 installer was configured. The configuration has been changed for 7u6.

Can you [try with 7u6](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html) and let us know if it resolves the problem?

Bug if you are interested: [Bug ID: 7145760 JDK Installation broken on WinXP since 7u2, worked in 7u1](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7145760)

Answer (score 0):

To edit the PATH environment variable in Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7:
Click the "Start" button ⇒ "Control Panel" ⇒ "System" ⇒ (Vista/7 only) "Advanced system settings".
Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ "Environment Variables..."
In "System Variables" box, scroll down to select "PATH" ⇒ "Edit..."
In "Variable value" field, INSERT "c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin" (assume that this is your JDK's binary directory) IN FRONT of all the existing directories, followed by a semi-colon (;) which separates the JDK's binary directory from the rest of the existing directories. DO NOT DELETE any existing entries; otherwise, some existing applications may not run.
Variable name  : PATH
Variable value : c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin;....exiting entries....

Comment: It's always a good idea to include full answers rather than providing a link as an answer.  If that link goes stale in the future, this will lead someone with the same problem to a dead end.  Links are ok for additional reading or reference.

Comment: I checked the C:\Program Files\ folder and found a Java folder with empty jre folders and I deleted that.  I again retried double-clicking the installer, but it is a no go. :(  I don't think the path matters if the jdk isn't even installed yet..